# Vlookup not reflecting proper values on Apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've made the following script to look for an specific word in a column in apps script:

```
function findCompliant() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet23');
  var rg = sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow() - 1,1);
  var v = rg.getValues();
  var searchTerm = "true";  
  const result = v.map(row => row[0].toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerm) > 1 ? ["It is true"]: ["it is false"])
  sh.getRange(2,3,result.length,1).setValues(result);
}
```

But when I try to lookup the "true" value in the column it all show up as "it is false", which it's incorrect as the data looks like this (it is a slice of the column that I'm looking for there's a total of 16 columns before my lookup column):

| compliant |
| --- |
| TRUE |
| FALSE |
| FALSE |
| TRUE |
| TRUE |

I don't know what the code is doing as when I console log the getValues array it's getting me all the information however at the time of inserting the new column all the values are showing as everything is false, what can be causing the issue in here?

EDIT the results are coming like these:

[image]

Comment: you're comparing to string 'true' when data example has different string: 'TRUE'

Comment: Just change the `>1 to >-1`

Comment: yes it seems that was the issue with the code, thanks a lot Cooper

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it like this:

This is working I believe

```
function findCompliant() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet0');//changed sheet name
  var rg = sh.getRange(2,17,sh.getLastRow() - 1,1);
  var v = rg.getValues();
  var searchTerm = "true";  
  const result = v.map(row => row[0].toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerm) > -1 ? ["It is true"]: ["it is false"]);//perhap you wish to say greater than -1
  sh.getRange(2,18,result.length,1).setValues(result);//changed column
}
```

perhaps you wish to say greater than minus one

Here's 17 and 18 of my sheet zero.

| COL17 | COL18 |
| --- | --- |
| 1true | It is true |
| 12true | It is true |
| 1TRUE | It is true |
| 12TRUE | It is true |
| TRUE | It is true |
| FALSE | it is false |

Comment: still giving me the same error, I've went ahead and make a sheet with only one column for true and false and try your code and everything is the same showing as "it is false"

Comment: can you supply a column of data in a table?

Comment: yeah you can use the same example that is on the question, that's the one that I'm using to test the code

Comment: is that you data?

Comment: If that's your data then that's the problem because all of you true or TRUE are at index 0 not 1.  Actually, you may have a space there I can't tell but you need atleast two space so that it is greater than one

Comment: I edited the code and added a screenshot on how the data looks after running the code

Comment: I really think that this line ` const result = v.map(row => row[0].toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerm) > 1 ? ["It is true"]: ["it is false"]);` should be ` const result = v.map(row => row[0].toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerm) > -1 ? ["It is true"]: ["it is false"]);`